# return part of a string

Tags: php

I'm trying to return a certain part of a string. I've looked at `substr`, but I don't believe it's what I'm looking for.

Using this string:

```
/text-goes-here/more-text-here/even-more-text-here/possibly-more-here
```

How can I return everything between the first two `//` i.e. `text-goes-here`

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$str="/text-goes-here/more-text-here/even-more-text-here/possibly-more-here";
$x=explode('/',$str);
echo $x[1]; 
print_r($x);// to see all the string split by /
```

Comment: Oops, I thought `explode` returned a string, not an array. Makes sense now! Thanks!

Comment: mr manual says "Returns an array of strings created by splitting the string parameter on boundaries formed by the delimiter. "

Comment: Yup, haven't look at `explode` for a while. Reading over it again. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$String = '/text-goes-here/more-text-here/even-more-text-here/possibly-more-here';

$SplitUrl = explode('/', $String);

# First element
echo $SplitUrl[1];  // text-goes-here

# You can also use array_shift but need twice
$Split = array_shift($SplitUrl);
$Split = array_shift($SplitUrl);

echo $Split;  // text-goes-here
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The explode methods above certainly work. The reason for matching on the second element is that PHP inserts blank elements in the array whenever it starts with or runs into the delimiter without anything else. Another possible solution is to use regular expressions:

```
<?php
$str="/text-goes-here/more-text-here/even-more-text-here/possibly-more-here";

preg_match('#/(?P<match>[^/]+)/#', $str, $matches);

echo $matches['match'];
```

The (?P<match> ... part tells it to match with a named capture group. If you leave out the ?P<match> part, you'll end up with the matching part in $matches[1]. $matches[0] will contain the part with the forward slashes like "/text-goes-here/".

Answer (score 0):

Just use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
preg_match('@/([^/]+)/@', $string, $match);
$firstSegment = $match[1]; // "text-goes-here"
```

where

```
@    - start of regex (can be any caracter)
/    - a litteral /
(    - beginning of a capturing group
[^/] - anything that isn't a litteral /
+    - one or more (more than one litteral /)
)    - end of capturing group
/    - a litteral /
@    - end of regex (must match first character of the regex)
```